# Beginning Java: How to pass an input file into a 2D array

Tags: java

I am having some issues understanding what Java wants syntactically for the program to work. The program is supposed to read the input file and then print out its contents. Once I do that, I will know how to manipulate its contents.

For example, my input file could look something like this:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class stats1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("numbers.tex"));
int[][] numbers = new int[s.nextInt()][s.nextInt()];
for (int row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++)
    for(int col =0; col < numbers[row].length; col++)
      numbers[row][col]=s.nextInt(); 
      System.out.print(numbers[row][col] + " ");
  } 

}
```

Comment: So? It doesn't work? It gives error? What is the question?

Comment: Looking at the code I can already spot that a bracket is needed in the 2nd for loop.  for (col ..) { // numbers and system out statement }

Comment: +1 to @JeremyUnruh. **Always** use curly braces around your blocks, even if they only contain one instruction. More consistent, easier to read, and no chance for a bug.

Comment: I fixed it with a bracket but it's not reading all of the numbers

Comment: Does first line contain the expected size of the 2D array? Or you won't know it until the entire file is read?

Comment: @ Ronixus: How do I do that without using     int[][] numbers = new int[3][3]; ? I want to somehow use s.nextInt();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `{` and `}` after the second loop:

```
for (int row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++)
    for(int col =0; col < numbers[row].length; col++) {
      numbers[row][col]=s.nextInt(); 
      System.out.print(numbers[row][col] + " ");
    }
```

I recommend you to use a braces around the outer loop too, to prevent such errors in the future.

Note that in your case, `numbers.length` will be 1 and `numbers[row].length` will be 2. (Since you declared and defined your array using `nextInt` which took 1 and 2 from the file.

Then, your loop will run only on 3 and 4. So your output will be 3,4.

I suggest you to put in the first line the dimension of the matrix. And in order to see a "matrix shape", you need to print an empty line after the inner loop finishes.

Alternatively, you can first count the number of rows and columns, this way you won't need to add in the first line the dimension.